# Metro style apps vs Desktop mode apps vs Silverlight

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, silverlight, microsoft-metro

I have probed some informations about the Windows 8 and Metro style apps and i have few questions,

1. How does the Metro style apps evolve in the future or dominate in the market? Does it be the future of Windows?
2. How about the existing and future desktop mode apps?
3. How will it affect the silverlight and WPF's future?

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those gray, subjective questions. I've voted to close this question because it's not a great fit for StackOveflow.

Even so, I'll attempt to answer your question:

> How does the Metro style apps evolve in the future or dominate in the
>   market? Does it be the future of Windows?

Yes, Metro apps will be the future of Windows. They'll be the only kind of Windows app that will run on Windows, Windows Phone, and Windows Tablets. It will dominate in the Windows market because those apps will be the only safe, verified apps. If Windows 8 can take off -- either via desktop, phone, or tablet -- it will be a popular platform for developing consumer apps.

> How about the existing and future desktop mode apps?

They'll continue working for the foreseeable future. However, it's clear they'll be second class citizens: you'll need to launch the classic desktop before using old Windows apps.

> How will it affect the silverlight and WPF's future?

Metro apps will decrease WPF and Silverlight usage; Silverlight especially, since web plugins like Silverlight don't run in the default Metro Internet Explorer. (Again, you'll have to launch the classic desktop, then the desktop IE, in order to run SL apps.)

Over time, I expect Metro to fully supplant desktop UI technologies on Windows. It will take time, though.